# Why can't I call poll_read() on tokio::fs::File?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a struct that encapsulates `File` struct and I want this struct to implement `AsyncRead` trait so it could be used instead of `File` in some other part of the code:

```
struct TwoWayFile<'a> {
    reader: &'a File,
}

impl<'a> AsyncRead for TwoWayFile<'a> {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut [u8],
    ) -> Poll<io::Result<usize>> {
        self.reader.poll_read(cx, buf)
    }
}
```

According to the docs `tokio::fs::File` already implements `tokio::io::AsyncRead` but the compiler says the opposite:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `poll_read` found for reference `&'a tokio::fs::file::File` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:44:21
   |
44 |         self.reader.poll_read(cx, buf)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&'a tokio::fs::file::File`
```

What is missing here? Why I can't call the method that is already defined for `File`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is likely that the `poll_read` method is implemented on `Pin<&mut Self>`, not on `&self`. This means you can only call it on a pinned mutable reference, and not a plain reference.

You can pin your reference on the heap using `Box::pin` or on the "async stack" using the `pin_mut!` macro, and should then be able to call the method.

Comment: I replaces a reference to `File` in my struct with a value and called `poll_read` on a `Pin` and it worked! Thanks!